# error if i want toupgrade

Tags: magento2.3.3

## php bin/magento setup:upgrade

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to alloc ate 32768 bytes) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MagentoEbenezer\vendor\donatj\phpuseragentpa
>   rser\src\UserAgentParser.php on line 128
>
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 3 2768 bytes) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MagentoEbenezer\vendor\donatj\phpuseragentparser\
>   src\UserAgentParser.php on line 128

**please can i help me to solve this**

Answer (score 1):

You are running hitting your memory limit while updating, the options you have are;

1) Increasing the PHP Memory limit in `PHP.ini` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41724822/10162046)

2) Rerun the command with a tempory higher memory limit `php -d memory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:upgrade`